# Openshift: adf application not runnig on openshift

Tags: glassfish, openshift

I've installed glassfish server and some additional libraries to run adf application using following link 
http://multikoop.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/adf-essentials-in-redhat-cloud.html

I've copied .ear file in the /app-root/repo/diy/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy. when I run the app, its throwing below error.

```
    Not Found
    `/testApp/faces/test.jsf' not found.
    WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.8.7/2011-06-30) at <app>-<domain>.rhcloud.com:80
```

a) I am not sure if the glassfish was installed properly as I just used

```
wget http://download.java.net/glassfish/3.1.2.2/release/glassfish-3.1.2.2.zip

unzip glassfish-3.1.2.2.zip
```

is there any way to find that out?

b) how can access the admin console?

c) does it deploy the app just copying the .ear file in the autodeploy directory?

d) how can I resolve above issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

While the admin interface doesn't work on this one either, there is a glassfish quickstart located here https://github.com/shekhargulati/glassfish4-openshift-quickstart that should get you up and running. I would recommend starting there and then following the instructions to get the adf components installed.

Comment: hi, i am using https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-glassfish3-sample since adf application can only run on glassfish 3. when i deploy the app, in server.log I get this error /var/lib/openshift/<userid>/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/action_hooks/start: line 10: ../../../bin/asadmin: Permission denied

Comment: here is the code for start action_hook - cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/
mv domain.xml domain.xml_2
sed "s/$( grep serverName domain.xml_2 | cut -d\" -f 2 )/${OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}/g" domain.xml_2 > domain.xml
../../../bin/asadmin start-domain &> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/server.log